# How do I get pip from my virtualenv to install to the virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I'm not sure how many of these ingredients matter, but I try running a bash script I wrote a long time ago that creates a virtualenv and activates it. I changed it to use python3 as the python version. However, this seems to break the virtualenv and tries to pip install into the global site-packages.

How do I get pip from a python3 virtualenv to install into that virtualenv?

```sh
PYTHON=${PYTHON:-python3}
VENV_DIR="bld_tests_env"
$PYTHON -m virtualenv --python=$PYTHON $VENV_DIR

set -x
source $VENV_DIR/bin/activate
which -a python
which -a pip
ls -l `which pip`
pip --version
```

gives me the following output

```sh
+ which -a python
<code path>/staging/bld_tests_env/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
+ which -a pip
<code path>/staging/bld_tests_env/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
+ ls -l `which pip`
<code path>/staging/bld_tests_env/bin/pip
+ pip --version
pip 20.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Can anybody explain to me why invoking pip after activating the virtualenv still references the global installation?

Comment: Are you executing the script with sudo privileges? I'm not entirely sure about this case, but virtual environments get a bit weird when it comes to sudo...

Comment: @NicolasForstner `which -a` show proper paths to `python` and `pip` — the 1st ones are in the virtual env.

Comment: @xaviersjs Can we see the shebang `head -1 $(which pip)`

Comment: It's `#!/<code path>/staging/bld_tests_env/bin/python`.

Comment: It really looks like I'm executing the right pip executable, but that pip executable doesn't have the right PYTHONPATH! I hacked my pip script in the virtualenv and added some lines to the main function ```from pip import _internal
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(_internal.cli.main.__file__)
    print(sys.argv)``` and it outputs "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py" and "['<code path>/staging/bld_tests_env/bin/pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip']"

Comment: I'm concerned that running from within a bash script is somehow different in python3 vs python2 on a mac. It looks like the main logic of the virtualenv pip is "sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])" which doesn't seem to have any effect for my setup.

Comment: Compare `bld_tests_env/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` with `/usr/local/bin/python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/Users/stefansullivan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213974/discussion-between-xaviersjs-and-phd).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an explanation for why it's so broken with virtualenv, but I did learn that venv is a built-in module since python 3.3 https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

If I switch from

```sh
$PYTHON -m virtualenv --python=$PYTHON $VENV_DIR
```

to

```sh
$PYTHON -m venv $VENV_DIR
```

then everything seems to work as expected.

My guess is that virtualenv is not properly supported on python3 and nobody notices because nobody bothers to use the pip package for it.